# Add timestamp to R CMD BATCH outfile name

Tags: linux, r, shell

I want to run a script, and name the outfile.  The default looks like this:

```
R CMD BATCH $HOME/test.R $HOME/runoutput/test_
```

How do I add a timestamp to the name?

Something like this:

```
R CMD BATCH $HOME/test.R $HOME/runoutput/test_$(date +"%F_%H_%M_%S")
```

Comment: Use backticks around `date +"%F_%H_%M_%S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't show backticks in the comments, see below:

```
R CMD BATCH $HOME/test.R $HOME/runoutput/test_`date +"%F_%H_%M_%S"`
```

Comment: @Paul you could also get timestamp within your R script.